# Use One Month Calendar to Populate 2 Text Boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, monthcalendar

I was wondering if you could use one month calendar to populate 2 text boxes on a windows form.  One for the beginning date and one for the end date.  I can figure out how to populate both text boxes with the click on the calendar but now how to populate start date with click 1, clear the calendar, then populate end date with the 2nd calendar click.

Is this possible, and if so how would I achieve this in C# windows form?

Comment: You could use a [DateTimePicker.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker(v=vs.110).aspx) Otherwise I'm not really sure I understand your question...

Comment: @alstonp - if I switched it to a DateTimePicker what would the syntax be to achieve my desired result?

Comment: Again, I'm not really sure what your asking for here. Do you automatically want to populate the end date based on the start date?

Comment: @alstonp No, I want to pick one date, have it populate txtbox1.  once txtbox1.Text != Null clear the date selected on the calendar.  Select a 2nd date on the calendar and populate txtbox2 with this 2nd date.  Does that help clarify what I am after?

Comment: Yes, thank you :) I see, let me write something up quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the "Date Selected" event as seen below:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        mthCalendarMaster.DateSelected += mthCalendarMaster_DateSelected;
    }

    private void mthCalendarMaster_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text))
            textBox1.Text = e.Start.ToShortDateString();
        else
            textBox2.Text = e.Start.ToShortDateString();
    }
```

**Note:** It is not the greatest idea to define your event handlers in the form's constructor.

Comment: Is there other alterations needed to syntax?  If I simply copy/paste this syntax into my procedure nothing happens?  textbox1 does not get the value of selected from the mthCalenarMaster.

Comment: You need to bind the event:

Comment: Stepping through my code it only hits the block and never any of the code you posted:        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: @MasterOfStupidQuestions Did you set a breakpoint and try to set through after clicking on the control?

Comment: @MasterOfStupidQuestions Also, is the name of your form "Form1"?

Comment: Yes it is named Form1 - yes I set a breakpoint and nothing outside of the public Form1() event runs. (Even with your update)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59317/discussion-between-alstonp-and-masterofstupidquestions).

Answer (score 0):

This will make the 2 textboxes have the currently startdate of the month and end date all binded through the binding source :

```
        BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetSource();
            textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", source, "Start", true);
            textBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", source, "End", true);
        }

        private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {
            SetSource();
        }

        private void SetSource()
        {
            source.DataSource = monthCalendar1.GetDisplayRange(true);
        }
    }
```

We call SetSource() in the DateChanged handler to keep the textboxes sync with calendar iteration(previous month,next month...).

Comment: Same scenario, I added your code to my project and the text boxes never show the date selected on the month calendar...

Comment: @MasterOfStupidQuestions  sorry but impossible unless what you asked in your question is something else.this will bind the textboxes to the start and end dates in the currently displayed moth on the monthcalendar.

Comment: My 2 textboxes are named textbox1 & textbox2 -- and the calendar is named mthCalendarMaster -- I changed the name of the calendar in your syntax but the text boxes are not populating with selected dates...

Comment: Stepping through my code it only hits the         public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } and none of the syntax above

Comment: ahhhh...you have to set up the event handlers.doubleclicking the form in the designer will hook up the form load event,for the datechanged also in the designer click the monthcalendar then in the properties window on the events search for date changed and double-click it it will as the load for the form generate these 2 handlers and then you can paste the code.